# jq json move object to nested object and iterating over unknown names/numbers of objects

Tags: json, stream, nested, key, jq

I've been looking over several examples of 'jq' parsing of json strings, all very helpful, but not conclusive for my particular problem

Here's my input json :

```
{
    "outcome" : "TrBean",
    "result" : {"TrAct" : {
        "executiontime" : 16938570,
        "invocations" : 133863,
        "waittime" : 4981
    }}
}
{
    "outcome" : "WwwBean",
    "result" : {}
}
{
  "outcome": "CRFeatureBean",
  "result": {
    "CRChannels": {
      "executiontime": 78127,
      "invocations": 9983,
      "waittime": 213
    },
    "getCRChannels": {
      "executiontime": 98704,
      "invocations": 10113,
      "waittime": 212
    },
    "getCRToMigrate": {
      "executiontime": 32,
      "invocations": 4,
      "waittime": 0
    },
    "getCRId": {
      "executiontime": 28198633,
      "invocations": 747336,
      "waittime": 19856
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to feed graphite via collectd exec plugin (PUTVAL), so I need info in one line.  I tried with `./jq '.result|to_entries[]|{"method:" .key, "inv": .value.invocations}|"PUTVAL \(.method)/invoke:\(.invokes)"'` ... but I need to have "outcome" in every line too.

Also I do not know the amount, nor the names of the result-objects

So, I'd like to end up with :

```
TrBean_TrAct
WwwBean
CRFeatureBean_CRChannels
CRFeatureBean_getCRChannels
CRFeatureBean_getCRToMigrate
CrFeatureBean_getCRId
```

Answer (score 0):

The following jq filter produces the desired output when jq is invoked with the -r command-line option:

```
((.result | keys_unsorted[]) // null) as $key
| if $key == null then .outcome
  else [.outcome, $key] | join("_")
  end
```

There are of course many possible variations, e.g.

```
((.result | keys_unsorted[]) // null) as $key
| [.outcome, ($key // empty)]
| join("_")
```

or if you want a short one-liner:

```
.outcome + ("_" + (.result | keys_unsorted[]) // null)
```

In any case, the key to simplicity here is to generate the keys of `.result` as a stream.  Handling the "edge case" makes the solution slightly more complicated than it would otherwise be, i.e. `.outcome + "_" + (.result | keys_unsorted[])`

Example invocation: jq -r -f program.jq input.json

Comment: Hi Peak, that's really elegant; but how would I get the values (invocations, executionme...) from the .result objects also in there ?

Comment: You could use `.[$key]`, for example.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, or I might have not been clear enough :)  Where do I put `.[$key]` in the command to get invocations, executiontime, waittime in the output ?

Comment: If you cannot figure it out from the online tutorial and manual, you should probably ask a new SO Q (following as always the mcve guidelines).